# Ubuntu Server 12.04: черный экран после GRUB

Tags: экран, ubuntu, сервер, linux

Сервер стоит на ноутбуке Acer. Работает - это я вижу, пингуя его внутри сети. Но вот на экран ничего не выводится. В чем может быть причина и как починить?

В режиме *recovery mode* грузится нормально - экран работает. Правда во время загрузки выдается сообщение:

```
Starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]
```

UPD. Фрагмент результата выполнения команды *lspci* по SSH, имеющий отношение к монитору:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
```

UPD. К вопросу о передаче параметров ядру во время загрузки. В режиме передачи параметров при загрузке вижу вот это:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu, c Linux 3.5.0-34-generic'recordfailgfxmode $linux_gfx_modeinsmod gzioinsmod part_msdosinsmod ext2set root='(hd0,msdos3)'search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0b397bd2-1151-0e04-8cd0-73e0eb38dd25linux /boot/vmlinux-3.5.0-34-generic root=UUID=0b397bd2-1151-0e04-8cd0-73e0eb38dd25 roinitrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-34-generic
```

Добавил в третью с низу строку vga=791, нажал F10 и случилось чудо - заработало. До перезагрузки. Потом опять черный экран.

Comment: Скорее всего Вы убили GUI, снесите оболочку и получите нормальный сервер, все это при условии, что ssh-server установлен. Если нет, я бы на Вашем месте восстановил с установочного дистрибутива... Сервер на ноуте - жесть, конечно!

Comment: Речь идет о чистовой установке. [Наученный горьким опытом](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/7633/linux-ubuntu-server-12-04-network-is-unreachable), GUI я не ставил, поэтому сносить нечего. А чем ноут в качестве железа плох? 2Гб оперативки, 77 Гб HHD - вроде как для обучения вполне нормально.

Comment: А что, Ctrl-Alt-F1, Alt-F1, ну или вообще консоль тоже не пашет? Тогда грузитесь в recovery mode, и смотрите последние логи НЕУДАЧНОЙ загрузки! Дело, похоже всё-таки, в видеодрайвере!

Comment: @pyatak - правил файл /etc/default/grub - безрезультатно. Можно подробнее, что именно нужно сделать? @areshin - пашет все, только монитор ничего не отображает в нормальном режиме: либо рековери мод, либо ssh. Где и какие логи стоит посмотреть? Спасибо.

Comment: логи в /var/log

Comment: Нет я имел ввиду передать параметр ядру в момент загрузки , как тут http://wiki.unixforum.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83._%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85._grub,_lilo

Comment: ох уже эти убунтоиды ))) пропишите vga=791 в (grub.conf\menu.list) в общем от версии груба(grub2\grub-legacy) зависит и сохраните файл.
Чтоб не было подобных вопросов рекомендую 2-3 раза установить gentoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в grub передать параметр ядру vga=791, это 1024x768,16 бит. Вероятно что ваш дисплей не отображает то разрешение которое грузится в норм режиме.

Comment: После перезагрузки все опять вернулось на круги своя.

Answer (score 0):

вставте строку /usr/bin/setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80 в файл /etc/rc.local

Comment: Не помогло.

Comment: самая первая строка в rc.local должна выглядеть так #!/bin/shследующей сторокой  /usr/bin/setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=80 сам файл должен быть исполняемым